# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ref.onSnapshot')

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Angular and Firebase Firestore throws TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ref.onSnapshot')

```
this.fbstore
      .collection(`claims`, ref => {
        let query:
          | firebase.default.firestore.CollectionReference
          | firebase.default.firestore.Query = ref;

          if(someValue === true) {
            return query.where('field1', '==', 20);
          }

          
      }).valueChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if `someValue` is false then query is not returned, adding else statement will solve the issue or add default `return query`. These types of errors are time consuming if you rely on IDE, Typescript to much, it's easy to see the problem on this sample code.

```
this.fbstore
      .collection(`claims`, ref => {
        let query:
          | firebase.default.firestore.CollectionReference
          | firebase.default.firestore.Query = ref;

          if(someValue === true) {
            return query.where('field1', '==', 20);
          }
       
         return query; // this will not run if someValue is true

      }).valueChanges();
```